# What glue can we use to fill cracks in a solid surface counter top?

Tags: bathroom, tile, crack

We noticed our bathroom counter is starting to crack and wanted to know if there is some sort of good glue for this. I think in the future it’ll need to be replaced but want to make sure it does not just fall right now.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: looks like a piece of natural stone used as a topper on a pony wall as the base for a 1/2 glass wall.   someone probably put too much weight on it and it has an overhang.  need more pictures from other angles to give suggestions.

Comment: Thank you! i added some more pictures, i thought this was a tile i am not 100% sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with glues is that you want something with the same properties as the substrate material. For stone tile, you need something with stone-like properties, e.g. grout. You only need a tiny bit and it's sold pre-mixed. In my experience, [siliconized acrylic grout](https://www.mapei.com/us/en-us/products-and-solutions/products/detail/keracaulk-u) works best for this sort of patch-up work.

Comment: Should i try to use a toothpick to push it downwards into the crack? also the grout will be white?
Edit: never mind i see they have different colors

Comment: Grout has a relatively low tensile strength, so it's not going to _repair_ this at all. It'll look nice, but it won't prevent further separation.

Comment: If you really want something solid -- tinted epoxy is (entirely too much of) a Thing...

Comment: Neither the regular grout, epoxy grout or siliconized grout are going to fix the problem in terms of adding structural strenght. It is just a cosmetic fix while the stone is replaced.